# How to use gmock SaveArgPointee with with std::shared_ptr of derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers, googlemock

I have a `BaseMessage` class from which I derive several different `DerivedMessage` subclasses and want to send them like this:

```
class BaseMessage {
public:
   virtual std::vector<uint8_t> data() const noexcept = 0;
   virtual ~BaseMessage() = default;
   [...]
}

class DerivedMessage : public BaseMessage {
public:
   [...]
   std::vector<uint8_t> data() const noexcept override { return m_data; }
private:
   std::vector<uint8_t> m_data;
}

// simplified 
class Tcp {
public
   virtual void sendMessage(std::shared_ptr<BaseMessage> msg) { write(msg->data());}
   [...]
};

class SomeClass {
public:
   SomeClass(Tcp& tcp) : m_tcp(tcp) {}
   void writeDataToRemote(std::shared_ptr<DerivedMessage> derived) const {
      m_tcp.sendMessage(derived);
private:
   Tcp m_tcp;
}
};
```

Now I want to write tests for `SomeClass` with gtest.

Therefore I mock the function of the TCP class:

```
class MockTcp : public Tcp {
MOCK_METHOD(void, sendMessage, (std::shared_ptr<ralco::CommandMsg> msg), (override));
[...]
}
```

Let's assume that all is simplified up to here but works.

So in the test, I'd like to inspect the argument given to `sendMessage` in the function `writeDataToRemote`.
I read about `::testing::SaveArg` and `::testing::SaveArgPointee` on StackOverflow (but not in the documentation, though).

```
TEST(SomeClassTest, writesMessageToSocket){
   MockTcp mockTcp;
   SomeClass sc(mockTcp);
   
   // >>>how to declare msgArg here?<<<
   EXPECT_CALL(mockTcp, sendMessage(_)).Times(1).WillOnce(::testing::SaveArgPointee<0>(msgArg));
   const auto derivedMsg = std::make_shared<DerivedMessage>();
   sc.writeDataToRemote(derivedMsg);
   // further inspection of msgArg follows
}
```

As written in the code comment, I don't know how to declare the `msgArg` variable so that it  can be assigned the actual argument given to `sendMessage`. When using `SaveArg` I think I'd get a dangling pointer and doing it as above I get errors because the message cannot be copy-assigned. Any hints apreciated.

Comment: You already have a pointer to `derivedMsg`. Does real implementation of `SomeClass` modify the pointer (i.e. changes the pointed-to object)? Or does it only modify contents of the pointed-to object and pass it further to `Tcp` object?

Comment: In my real implementation it would be more of a setter function in `SomeClass`.  I pass in a value, create a `DerivedMessage`, modify the data and pass it to `sendMessage`. Just wanted to simplify my example here.

Comment: I try to clarify, because unless `SomeClass` ignores its input and reassigns the pointer before passing it to `Tcp` (i.e. does `derived = std::make_shared(something_new);`), you already have the pointer in test - `derivedMsg` points to it. You don't need to save it anywhere. You could actually verify if this is the same pointer passed to mock (`EXPECT_CALL(mockTcp, sendMessage(derivedMsg));`) and you can check properies of pointed-to object of `derivedMsg`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Maybe I oversimplified it wrongly ^^ In my real scenario I have no real knowledge about the message passed to `sendMessage`, thats why I need to assign it to a variable.
It would be something like this in reality
`
void writeDataToRemote(/* someDataVector*/ ) const {
      //construct derived
     // set someDataVector to derived
      m_tcp.sendMessage(derived); 
}
`
but that was not my point here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you actually want to just save and inspect the considered `shared_ptr`, so it is enough to use `SaveArg`:

```
    MockTcp mockTcp;
    SomeClass sc(mockTcp);
    std::shared_ptr<BaseMessage> bm;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockTcp, sendMessage(_)).Times(1).WillOnce(::testing::SaveArg<0>(&bm));  // it will effectively do bm = arg;
    const auto derivedMsg = std::make_shared<DerivedMessage>();
    sc.writeDataToRemote(derivedMsg);
    // verify that the argument that you captured is indeed pointing to the same message
    std::cout << derivedMsg.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << bm.get() << std::endl;
```

The common misunderstanding of `SaveArgPointee` is that it assigns value pointed by the arg to your local variable in test, which in your case maybe is not a good idea, because it would invoke a copy constructor of Message.

Alternatively I can recommend using `Invoke`. It is very generic and easy to use. You can e.g. capture the desired argument like that:

```
    MockTcp mockTcp;
    SomeClass sc(mockTcp);
    std::shared_ptr<BaseMessage> bm;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockTcp, sendMessage(_)).Times(1).WillOnce(::testing::Invoke([&bm](auto arg) { bm = arg; }));
    const auto derivedMsg2 = std::make_shared<DerivedMessage>();
    sc.writeDataToRemote(derivedMsg2);
    std::cout << derivedMsg2.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << bm.get() << std::endl;
```

Or using a raw pointer to `BaseMessage`:

```
    BaseMessage* rawBm = nullptr;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockTcp, sendMessage(_)).Times(1).WillOnce(Invoke([&rawBm](auto arg) { rawBm = arg.get(); }));
    const auto derivedMsg2 = std::make_shared<DerivedMessage>();
    sc.writeDataToRemote(derivedMsg2);
    std::cout << derivedMsg2.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << rawBm << std::endl;
```

Comment: That does the trick, thank you, especially for the hint to `Invoke`, I will have a look at it.
However, I do not get why I must pass the reference to the shared_ptr into SaveArg. Can you explain that?

Comment: Yep, because you want to change the value of your pointer (`bm = something`, not `*bm = something`) and I guess that behind `SaveArg` magic there is some function that takes your variable, so if you don't pass `&bm` it will work on a copy of it. As for `[&bm]` in lambda capture - the same, you want to allow the lambda to change the local variable.

Comment: Alright, that makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!